# Intellij Idea - "show selected element" like in eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea

does idea has the same stuff "**show selected element**" like in eclipse?
What it does is hides all other code and shows only selected method and its body. Here is an example http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/0/05/Show_Selected_Element_Only.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it hasn't... You can [create a request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com) for them.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, but try this similar way around:
 -Go to the "Structure" view
 -Click on the method name or press F4. This will set focus to the method code

I hope it helps.